# Iterate and modify Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, hashtable, ienumerator

I am trying to implement solution for problem explined on http://users.metropolia.fi/~dangm/blog/?p=67.
I am new to c# language.I want to iterate through the dictionary using enumerator and for a particular condition.So there are two variables current and previous.current points to first element of dictionary.previous points to previous element in dictionary.While iterating over dictionary I am iterating like foll

```
previous=current;
current.MoveNext();
```

The problem is when we iterate first time thru whole dictionary previous points to last element in dictionary and current  points to random keyvalue pair RawVariable(0,0).But now for when we iterate second time through dictionary i want current to point to first element in dictionary.how do i make current point to some element that has a particular key or value

Here is my code snippet

```
 public void falling_disks(int[] A, int[] B)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> filledDictionary = filldictionary(d1, A);
        //previous stores the previous element in dictionary
        var previous = filledDictionary .GetEnumerator();
        //current stores next element of previous
        var current = filledDictionary .GetEnumerator();
        current.MoveNext();

        //for each incoming element in array B
        foreach (int ele in B)
        {

            //check if the current key is filled in hashtable h1 that is check if it
            //is already added
            if (!checkifthatvalueisfilled(current.Current.Key))
            {
                //if not check if current value is less than or equal to element
                while ((current.Current.Value >= ele))
                {
                    //assign previous to current
                    previous = current;
                    //move current to next position
                    current.MoveNext();
                }
                listofitemstoremove.Add(previous.Current.Key);

            }
            else
            {
                listofitemstoremove.Add(current.Current.Key);
            }

            foreach (int item in listofitemstoremove)
            {
                if (!(h1.ContainsKey(item)))
                    h1.Add(item, true);
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(listofitemstoremove.Capacity);
    }

    public bool checkifthatvalueisfilled(int key)
    {
        if (h1.ContainsValue(h1.ContainsKey(key)) == true)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is currently *very* unclear. Your code uses several variables and methods which aren't explained at all, and your text explanation is hard to understand. Please clarify.

Comment: A guess... assign `current` to the beginning `if (ele.Equals(b.Last())`?

Comment: do you want to search some value in the `Dictionary`

Comment: @Shekhar No.For each element in array B.I want to check whether that element is less than value in dictionary.If element in array B is greater than particular value in dictionary I am adding that keyvaluepair in a list<int,int>.Problem is when i am iterating i need to have 2 pointers current and previous.Previous follows current.Now when current points to last element in dictionary.Problem is explained on http://users.metropolia.fi/~dangm/blog/?p=67

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand.  Perhaps this is what you want to do at the beginning of your loop?

```
current = h1.GetEnumerator();
current.MoveNext();
```

Comment: i am doing current.movenext().But after iterating i want current to point to first element in dictionary which has key,value as (0,6).But we know that once we iterate dictionary,after last element in dictioary when we do current.movenext().current will point to raw variable.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you cant do it. Enumerator gives you consecutive access to the collection, that's the whole point. You cant suddenly move it to the particular element, without iterating to that element from the beginning.

Futheremore i dont see a single good reason to use enumerator. If you need refs to previous and current elements for your algorithm - you should store their keys, not enumerators. Also im pretty sure that these lines

```
 while ((current.Current.Value >= ele))
            {
                //assign previous to current
                previous = current;
                //move current to next position
                current.MoveNext();
            }
```

a) will throw an exception, when you ll reach the end of the collection b) wont work as expected since you are assigning reference types

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, but perhaps you want to change this:

```
                previous = current;
```

To this:

```
                previous.MoveNext();
```

That way 'previous' will always be one step behind 'current'. If you assign the variables the way you do in the original code, you just have two references to the 'current' object which is then incremented.